# How to make device token not to unregister when app is closed in ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

My ionic app doesn't receive push notifications when app is closed, although it receives when app is minimised.
 when i mail this issue to to "help@ionic.io" they replied as follows-
"Hm, they should definitely send unless you're unregistering the token when the app is closed. Can you double check your code to make sure you're not unregistering anything? Can you check the status of these notifications via the API?"
But i didn't write any code to unregister the token.
Here's my code

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPush, $resource) {
$ionicPush.register().then(function(t) {
    var token = t.token;
    return $ionicPush.saveToken(t);
    }).then(function(t) {
        alert(t.token);
    });
    $scope.$on('cloud:push:notification', function(event, data) {
        var msg = data.message;
        alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);
    })
}
```

})

Comment: Sending push notifications via firebase(using $http)

Answer (score 0):

You are listening for the push notification from a controller, try to listen from $rootScope on the apps `run` method like this example:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $ionicPush) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        $ionicPush.register().then(function(t) {
           var token = t.token;
           $ionicPush.saveToken(t);
        }).then(function(t) {
           console.log(t.token);
        });
        $rootScope.$on('cloud:push:notification', function(event, data) {
            var msg = data.message;
            console.log(msg);
        });
    });
});
```

It’s recommended to call register() every time the app is opened so the device is always registered and ready for notifications.

Comment: Its not working. I am sending push notifications via firebase(http request)